# Community Welcome Email Does Not Show In Activity History

Tags: community, email, customer-portal, activityhistory

Just wondering if it's possible to make your community welcome email show in the Activity History for that account.
It does not do it by default, but I'm sure there must be some trigger that I can leveagre off of to track it in Activity history.
Thanks
Paul

Answer (score 0):

It is unfortunate that admin/developers have no control over the welcome emails except the option of which profile it should be sent for and even if it should be sent in the first place. Having welcome emails tied down a Profile can sometimes be dangerous in my eyes as mistakingly activating the welcome message for a Profile will automatically send the email to each user.

One approach I would recommend is making use of [Workflow Rules](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Workflow_Rules). A Workflow rule will give you the option to send a welcome email designed by you or your team but you can also create a task and place that on the Contact record. If you have "Roll up activities to a contact's primary account" feature enabled from the Activity Settings, all those tasks will appear on the Account.